# How to avoid index out p bound exception from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to do a substring  of an arraylist ,but when the list is empty i am getting index out of bound exception 
this is my code

```
if(interviewTimingToFrom1.size()>0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < interviewTimingToFrom1.size(); i++) {       
        String str = interviewTimingToFrom1.get(i).substring(0, 
                                interviewTimingToFrom1.get(i).length() - 3);
        subInterviewTiming1.add(str);
    }
}

if (interviewTimingToFrom2.size()>0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < interviewTimingToFrom2.size(); i++) {
        String str = interviewTimingToFrom2.get(i).substring(0,
                               interviewTimingToFrom2.get(i).length() - 3);
        subInterviewTiming2.add(str);
    }
}
```

Here when `interviewTimingToFrom2` and `interviewTimingToFrom1` is empty then i am getting index out of bound how to solve this

Comment: The exception is likely not thrown on getting elements from your `List`, but on the unchecked `substring` operations on its elements, i.e. `interviewTimingToFrom1.get(i).length() - 3`

Comment: How to get rid of this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, this may help you to avoid exception.

```
String str = interviewTimingToFrom2.get(i).substring(0, interviewTimingToFrom2.get(i).length() > 3 ? interviewTimingToFrom2.get(i).length() - 3 : interviewTimingToFrom2.get(i).length());
```